Ubuntu 24.04 LTS fails to boot to kernel -48
Tower PC
Several weeks ago upgraded from 23.10 to 24.04 without issue. Used it without any boot problems until this AM. Have auto-update for security set and have allowed any updates.
This morning during boot, it simply would not pass the IRQ page. Just hangs there.
Tried to boot in safe mode, same problem. So dropped to the only other kernel shown on the Grub page and that boots. Using Terminal on the desktop, did a sudo update. That showed just one issue with one of the programs, KiCad, having an unmet dependency. And it says 'Some packages could not be installed' but no listing. Broken packages list is null.
6.8.0-47-generic is the kernel I'm using now as that continues past the IRQ page and gets to the pswrd page. The kernel 6.8.0-48-generic or -48 safe mode will not boot.
What do I do to restore? Or ID the problem?
Note I have two HDD drives that I just cloned the day before yesterday and I was using the cloned HDD when this problem appeared but have dropped back to the uncloned original. Both drives are stalling at the same IRQ page so this may be a hardware problem but I don't know how to ID it.
I have noticed that my front panel USB ports are not shown in Files any longer though they were working earlier this AM when I tried to run Boot-repair...which didn't work correctly. Command lsusb shows the normal USB devices.
Is there a way to narrow down the problem? Thanks.
Edit: It really strange how this problem just cropped up, then when I moved back to my original drive from the clone, the boot problem appeared there too. Note these HDDs are unpowered when I'm using the other one. So, thinking it must be a hardware issue, I moved the drives over to my backup PC, completely different mobo and hardware, and same thing, it'll only boot to kernel -47 and freezes on kernel -48. Other then not being able to boot normally, it's working fine on kernel -47.
EDIT: It's not working normally on -47 as it won't allow an upgrade. When I do an update && upgrade, it behaves as though it's going to do something but ends up with this:
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.8.0-48-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.8.0-48-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


EDIT: Since I got zero answers for this question, I gave up, made a full clone of the HDD, then installed 24.04 from a live SD choosing a full format wiping out the original install. Booted normally, and after spending hours installing my favorite apps and Home folder files, it's back to some semblance of normal.
